# How to add jcenter/jitpack as remote repository into apache archiva?

Tags: maven, gradle, archiva, jcenter, jitpack

I want to have a private repository manager to not download all the packages from internet every time. I decide to go with Apache Archiva.

At the moment I want to add jitpack.io and jcenter.bintray.com to my remote repositories. I've done as following picture but it doesn't do any good and I can't get for example "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5" from my private repository.

How can I properly add jitpack.io and jcenter into my Archiva?

Answer (score 1):

Dagger is on [maven central now](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.dagger%7Cdagger-compiler%7C2.11%7Cjar) so this is now moot but in order to get jitpack.io into archiva you need to add it as a proxy connector first at `#proxyconnectors`, and then as a remote repository under `#repositorylist` -> `Remote Repository Management`.

I haven't had any luck getting jcenter into Archiva - I was only able to get it to work by adding bintray repositories directly through their `"Set me up!"` button with a wrench icon on it, e.g., using a URL like http://dl.bintray.com/netlogo/NetLogo-JVM as the repository.